# Count unique elements within nested object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to find a fast and efficient way to count the number of distinct skus in this array by production date and the total number of times they are repeated please:-

```
var testArray = [
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 cocobear | sand | yrs 1-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 misha | mustard | mth 6-12"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 3-6"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 3-6"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 3-6"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 gloves | grey-marle"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 gloves | grey-marle"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 madison | grey"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 madison | grey"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 madison | grey"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 madison | grey"}}
];


output.inspect(testArray);
```

The expected output would be another array like this:-

```
resultArray = [
    {"production date": "2020-09-22",
    "skus": 4,
    "items": 10},
    {"production date": "2020-10-06",
    "skus": 2,
    "items": 6}    
];

output.inspect(resultArray);
```

I'm struggling because of the nested object array within the testArray.

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Jonathan

Comment: should these be grouped together or not?
A). "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3".
b). "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 3-6"

Comment: What elements of the `sku` make it unique? Is it just the portion after the date? Can it have spaces in it? Is the stuff after the first `|` just ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my way...

```js
const result =
  testArray.reduce((a,{fields},i,t)=>
    {
    if (!a.some(x=>x['production date']===fields['production date'])) 
      {
      let prods = t.filter(x=>x.fields['production date']===fields['production date'])
                    .map(m=>m.fields.sku)
        , skus = prods.filter((v,i,t)=>i==t.lastIndexOf(v))
        ;
      a.push( {'production date': fields['production date'], skus:skus.length, items:prods.length })
      }
    return a  
    },[])
```

full code:

```js
const testArray = 
  [ { fields: { 'production date': '2020-09-22', sku: '22-09-2020 cocobear | sand | yrs 1-3'  }} 
  , { fields: { 'production date': '2020-09-22', sku: '22-09-2020 misha | mustard | mth 6-12' }} 
  , { fields: { 'production date': '2020-09-22', sku: '22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3'    }} 
  , { fields: { 'production date': '2020-09-22', sku: '22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3'    }} 
  , { fields: { 'production date': '2020-09-22', sku: '22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3'    }} 
  , { fields: { 'production date': '2020-09-22', sku: '22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3'    }} 
  , { fields: { 'production date': '2020-09-22', sku: '22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3'    }} 
  , { fields: { 'production date': '2020-09-22', sku: '22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 3-6'    }} 
  , { fields: { 'production date': '2020-09-22', sku: '22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 3-6'    }} 
  , { fields: { 'production date': '2020-09-22', sku: '22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 3-6'    }} 
  , { fields: { 'production date': '2020-10-06', sku: '06-10-2020 gloves | grey-marle'        }} 
  , { fields: { 'production date': '2020-10-06', sku: '06-10-2020 gloves | grey-marle'        }} 
  , { fields: { 'production date': '2020-10-06', sku: '06-10-2020 madison | grey'             }} 
  , { fields: { 'production date': '2020-10-06', sku: '06-10-2020 madison | grey'             }} 
  , { fields: { 'production date': '2020-10-06', sku: '06-10-2020 madison | grey'             }} 
  , { fields: { 'production date': '2020-10-06', sku: '06-10-2020 madison | grey'             }} 
  ]
const result =
  testArray.reduce((a,{fields},i,t)=>
    {
    if (!a.some(x=>x['production date']===fields['production date'])) 
      {
      let prods = t.filter(x=>x.fields['production date']===fields['production date'])
                    .map(m=>m.fields.sku)
        , skus = prods.filter((v,i,t)=>i==t.lastIndexOf(v))
        ;
      a.push( {'production date': fields['production date'], skus:skus.length, items:prods.length })
      }
    return a  
    },[])

console.log( result )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best code-snippet for this problem, btw it solves the problem :)

1. We map on the array to access the nested objects :

```
const inspect = input => {
      const sortedData = testArray
            .map(item => item.fields)
};
```

2. Then we can reduce it to an object in which each key is a date, and the related value is the array of "skuts" for this date.

```
const inspect = input => {
      const sortedData = testArray
            .map(item => item.fields)
            .reduce((a, c) => {
                  const productionDate = c["production date"];
                  return {
                        ...a,
                        [productionDate]: (a[productionDate] || []).concat(c.sku)
                  }
      }, {})
};
```

3. Then we can sum-up this to an array, I used a Set to identify the number of different "skuts" in the array. And we already have the date and the total of "skuts" for this date (the array length).

```
// Final result
const inspect = input => {
      const sortedData = testArray
            .map(item => item.fields)
            .reduce((a, c) => {
                  const productionDate = c["production date"];
                  return {
                        ...a,
                        [productionDate]: (a[productionDate] || []).concat(c.sku)
                  }
      }, {})

      return Object.entries(sortedData).map(([k, v]) => ({
            "production date": k,
            items: v.length,
            skus: new Set(v).size
      }))
};
```

4. Finally you can use the function on your data :

```
inspect(testArray);
```

Note that 0 check is made, I assumed that your data will always have the right format.

I also assumed that two "skuts" where different if their content is different.

Answer (score 0):

Here a proposition which may work.

```js
const testArray = [
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 cocobear | sand | yrs 1-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 misha | mustard | mth 6-12"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 3-6"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 3-6"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 3-6"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 gloves | grey-marle"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 gloves | grey-marle"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 madison | grey"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 madison | grey"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 madison | grey"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 madison | grey"}}
];

let result = testArray.reduce((c, item) => {
  
  const date = item.fields['production date'];
  const sku = item.fields['sku'];
  
  if(!c.hasOwnProperty(date)){
    c[date] = {
        'production date': date,
        items: 0,
      skus: 0,
      set: new Set()
    };
  }
  
  c[date].items++;
  c[date].set.add(sku);
  c[date].skus = c[date].set.size;
  
  return c;
  
}, {});

result = Object.values(result);

console.log(result);
```

If needed you can loop your result to delete the set property

Comment: ? a result with  `"set": {}`

Comment: @MisterJojo This is only because the console from stackoverflow's code snippet editor dones't handle `Set` object. In fact the `result.set` is a [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of all unique shus

Answer (score 0):

Most of the previous answers seems a bit too hard IMO.
We could use the Set class and a simple reduce function I think

```js
const testArray = [
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 cocobear | sand | yrs 1-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 misha | mustard | mth 6-12"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 3-6"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 3-6"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 3-6"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 gloves | grey-marle"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 gloves | grey-marle"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 madison | grey"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 madison | grey"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 madison | grey"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 madison | grey"}}
];

// --- start here ---
let reduced = testArray
  .reduce((acc, cur) => {
    
    // use the production date as map key. this alow to easely groupby
    let curKey = cur.fields["production date"];
    if (! acc.hasOwnProperty(curKey)) {
      acc[curKey] = {
        // use a Set to maintain an array of uniq skus
        skus: new Set(),
        items: 0
      }
    }

    acc[curKey].skus.add(cur.fields.sku);
    acc[curKey].items++;

    return acc;
  }, {});

// final itaration to retrieve the size of each Set
Object.keys(reduced).map(function(key, index) {
  reduced[key].skus = reduced[key].skus.size
});

console.log(reduced);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var testArray = [
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 cocobear | sand | yrs 1-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 misha | mustard | mth 6-12"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 0-3"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 3-6"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 3-6"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-09-22", "sku": "22-09-2020 taylor | moon | mth 3-6"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 gloves | grey-marle"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 gloves | grey-marle"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 madison | grey"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 madison | grey"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 madison | grey"}},
{fields: {"production date": "2020-10-06", "sku": "06-10-2020 madison | grey"}}
];

const prodDate = {};
testArray.forEach(element => {
  //check each element in the array by their sku string to see if it is already used
  if (prodDate[element.fields["production date"]]) {
    //check that if the sku is the same and add to total
    if (!prodDate[element.fields["production date"]].actualSkus[element.fields.sku]){
        prodDate[element.fields["production date"]].actualSkus[element.fields.sku] = true
        prodDate[element.fields["production date"]].skus++;
    } 
    //this is add it regardless because every item is added
      prodDate[element.fields["production date"]].items++;
    
    
    //date is not used, format the result array
  } else {
    prodDate[element.fields["production date"]] = {
        "actualSkus":{ 
          //keeping each sku to compare it in each loop
          [element.fields.sku]: true
        },
        "skus": 1,
        "items": 1
    }
  }
});
//you can keep the next 2 lines for debugging
//Object.keys(prodDate).forEach(key => {delete prodDate[key].actualSkus });
//console.log(JSON.stringify(prodDate,0,2));

//create the result desired
const resultArray = [];
Object.keys(prodDate).forEach(key => {
  resultArray.push({"production date": key, "skus": prodDate[key].skus, "items": prodDate[key].items });
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(resultArray, 0, 2));
```